# XCode - horizontal scroll bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I just downloaded the new Xcode and why isn't there a scroll bar on the bottom? Is there an option to add it? There's only a scrollbar on the right...which is really annoying.

Comment: Horizontal scrollbar where?  In the editing window?  Does the code *need* a scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4 changes the editor so that by default all code is wrapped, instead of extending off screen.  Thats why you see no scroll bar.

However you can set it back - go to Xcode preferences, editing, then the "Indentation" tab.  In there is an option to "wrap lines to editor width".  If you uncheck that, you'll see scroll bars again and your code will extend off the screen.